# chrome browser is not opening with robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, google-chrome, robotframework

getting error :     WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

getting above error while running a robot script:
It is a simple code to open you tube in chrome browser.
it looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Browser}  Chrome
${URL}  https://www.youtube.com/

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
    Input Text  name:search_query  ted talk
    Click Button  id:search-icon-legacy
```

It is on ubuntu
using python2.7

- robotframework==3.0.2
- robotframework-mqttlibrary==0.7.0
- robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.3.0
- ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106

I tried updating chrome and chrome driver also.
I don't know what am i doing wrong,
please help.

Comment: ps: Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106

Comment: Remove `selenium2library` as it is older than `seleniumlibrary v.4.3.`

Comment: removed selenium2library, still nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying with robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.3.0 & robotframework==3.0.2

Update the robotframework-seleniumlibrary 4.3.0 to 3.0.1

pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.0.1

Add capabilities

```
${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver

Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    w3c    ${False}    
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    no-sandbox
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-setuid-sandbox
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-dev-shm-usage
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-single-click-autofill



Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    2x    1s
...    Create WebDriver    Chrome    alias=${Browser}    chrome_options=${chrome_options}

Go To    ${URL}
Input Text  name:search_query  ted talk
Click Button  id:search-icon-legacy
```

Comment: Still not working. having these versions now:  
robotframework==3.1.2   
robotframework-mqttlibrary==0.7.0   
robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0   
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.0.1

Comment: updated code as suggested by "Eknath", same error. :|

Comment: try this solution

Comment: where should i put this code, in *** Test Cases *** or in *** Variables ***.? Eknath

Comment: Under TC1, the above code is the replacement of keyword - "Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}"

Comment: did as u said Eknath, getting this now: Keyword 'Create WebDriver' failed after retrying 2 times. The last error was: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)

Comment: Can you pass the chrome executable_path = as an argument to Create WebDriver keyword,  the exception implies that the ChromeDriver was unable to initiate/spawn a new web browser i.e. Chrome Browser session. if you are still seeing the same issue, then download the latest chrome driver 80, check the chrome browser again (reinstall it), update below pip libraries  robotframework==3.1
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.1. I got the same issue and it got resolved by adding no-sandbox, disable-dev-shm-usage capabilities